# Javascript: camelize all API responses

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have this code for fetching data from an API:

```
  const newPromise = Promise.race([
    fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}news`),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('request timeout')), 10000)
    })        
  ]);

  newPromise
    .then(response => camelize(response.json()))
    .then(data => this.onSuccessNewsFetched(data))
    .catch(error => this.onErrorNewsFetched(error))
```

I would like to camelise the JSON response, but it is not working.
I would also like to do this operation for every API response I get without having to call the function over and over with each fetch. Also the timeout race could be abstracted since all requests to the API need it. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write a function that does it for you and use that instead

```
function betterFetch(url, options = { timeout: 10000 }) {
  const apiPromise = Promise.race([
    fetch(url),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('request timeout')), options.timeout)
    })
  ]);

  return apiPromise
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => camelize(data))
}
// later
betterFetch(`${process.env.API_URL}news`)
  .then(data => this.onSuccessNewsFetched(data))
  .catch(error => this.onErrorNewsFetched(error))
```